# How can I join multiple objects automatically in groups determined by how far away they are from each other?

Tags: modeling, scene

So I have a big level I made in blender intended for a game but I need to join models so that they become one. But there are 1057 objects in the scene and for me to join all of the objects together manually would take a while, and I don't want everything to be a single object. I basically need to join the stuff so that it becomes about 200 - 250 objects without me having to manually select equal amounts of objects to do that.

The reason I say "determined by how far away they are" is because it would really help if the things I joined were within a vicinity of each other, so the things joined are logical and in chunks instead of just "all the objects that share a material" or something.

Any addon or methods will help.

Comment: Hard to guess without knowing how your models are. But there is a general approach to do that named "k-means" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) and you can find implementations for Python: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2.html or http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html. You'll need to install the corresponding packages in the Blender Python env.

Answer (score 1):

**Make a Grid of view3d region and join via Border Select**

Made an operator that splits the 3d view into an i x j grid. Joins all the meshes in each grid sector using border select.  *Note this is a 2D approach, and assumes that looking at your level in top view and assigning a grid will suffice.  If your objects are spread more randomly in all three dimensions each joined selection would look more like a column.*

After running script below, find in *`view3d > object > Grid Join`* menu.

[image]

Did have the View All operator in the operator, but decided it may be better to let user choose view, and zoom into all objects wishes to join.

[image]
*Divide visible screen area into a grid with 16 x segments, and 9 y segments and join those selected by border select in each.*

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Join objects based on View3d Grid"""
    bl_idname = "view3d.grid_join"
    bl_label = "Grid Join"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    x_segments = IntProperty(default=16, min=1)
    y_segments = IntProperty(default=9, min=1)
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        scene = context.scene
        return len([o for o in scene.objects if o.type == 'MESH'])

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        joined_obs = []
        bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
        #bpy.ops.view3d.view_all()
        region = context.region
        print(region.width, region.height)
        w = region.width / self.x_segments
        h = region.height / self.y_segments
        for i in range(self.x_segments):
            xmin, xmax  = i * w, (i + 1) * w
            for j in range(self.y_segments):                
                ymin, ymax  = j * h, (j + 1) * h
                #print(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
                bpy.ops.view3d.select_border(
                       xmin=xmin, 
                       xmax=xmax,
                       ymin=ymin,
                       ymax=ymax,
                       deselect=False,
                       extend=False)
                for o in context.selected_objects:
                    o.select = o.type == 'MESH'
                if len(context.selected_objects):
                    scene.objects.active = context.selected_objects[0]
                    bpy.ops.object.join()
                    context.object.hide = True
                    joined_obs.append(context.object)

        for o in joined_obs:
            o.hide = False
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_draw(self, context):
    self.layout.operator("view3d.grid_join")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.prepend(menu_draw)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_draw)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
```